# Show 1 value in array

Tags: php, regex

I have a table with difference value that looks like this:

[image]

I always want to get the same value ie "Page:" except that this table varies depending on the document. The value "Page:" can be at position 8 as at position 11 etc.
How could I do to counter this?

Thank you.

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: Uhm use associative arrays?

Comment: `var_dump($array['page']);`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg_grep) to search for a value in array with a regex.

```
$array = array(
    "Producer:  Ascensio System",
    "Page size: 589 x 941",
    "Pages: 3",
    "File size: 12651 bytes"
);
$arrayValue = preg_grep('/\b(Pages)\b/i', $array);
$arrayKey = count($arrayValue) > 0 ? key($arrayValue) : false;
if ($arrayKey) {
    echo 'Found value <'.$arrayValue[$arrayKey].'> at key '.$arrayKey;
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Consider that `$arrayKey` and `$arrayValue` are related to the first regex match.

Comment: show "Found value  at key 4" but without value. That is, "1"

Comment: @Christopher which value you need to find exactly?

Comment: i need just result "Pages: 1"

Comment: Try... echo 'Found value <'.$array[$arrayKey].'> at key '.$arrayKey;

Comment: It's strange. Have you tried @GavinJackson solution?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be...

- Iterate over the array with `foreach`
- Test beggining of each array element for 'Pages:'
- When located, acquire value and optionally `break` out of loop, unless you're expecting multiple 'Pages:' elements within the array you're searching.

  ```
  $array = array(
      "Producer:  Ascensio System",
      "Page size: 589 x 941",
      "Pages: 3",
      "File size: 12651 bytes"
  ```

  );

  ```
  foreach ($array as $str){
      if(preg_match('/^Pages:/',$str)){
              echo($str);
              break;
      }
  ```

  }

Comment: Simpler I had to think of regex?